# Capture view-shot and save to device - React Native

Tags: react-native

I am developing an application where I have a button (TouchableHighlight) when pressing this button it is necessary to capture a screeshot of the current screen and save the file in the device.

My code does not show error, but when I press the button (TouchableHighlight) I get the message:

Image saved to file: ///data/user/0/com.appcamerav4/cache/ReactNative-snapshot-image8525057299267209213.jpg ***through Remote JS Debugging*** .

I can not open this directory and need to save the image to the device.

I'm new to react-native.

Follow my code below:

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Text, View, Image, StyleSheet, TouchableHighlight, WebView, StatusBar, Button } from 'react-native';
import { captureScreen } from "react-native-view-shot";

const zooMais = require('../imgs/zooMais.png');
const zooMenos = require('../imgs/zooMenos.png');
const imgScreeshot = require('../imgs/screeshot.png');


const btnZooMais = ()=>{
    alert("Zoo Mais");
    console.log("Zoom +");
  }
const btnZooMenos = ()=>{
    alert("Zoo Menos");
    console.log("Zoom +");
  }
const capitureScreen = ()=>{
    
    captureScreen({
        format: "jpg",
        quality: 0.8,
        }).then(
        uri => console.log("Image saved to", uri),
        error => console.error("Oops, snapshot failed", error)
        );
}
     
export default class Monitor extends Component {
    
    render() {
        return (  
          
            <View style={ style.viewPrincipal }>

                <StatusBar hidden />

                <View style={ style.viewImagem }  >                
                    <WebView
                        style={style.video}
                        automaticallyAdjustContentInsets={true}
                        scalesPageToFit={true}
                        startInLoadingState={false}
                        contentInset={{top: 0, right: 0, left: 0, bottom: 0}}
                        scrollEnabled={true}
                        source={{uri: 'https://facebook.github.io/react/logo-og.png'}} 
                        onNavigationStateChange = {this.handleNavigationStateChange}
                        />             
                </View>   
                
                <View style={ style.viewRodape }> 
                
                    <View style={style.viewMenu}>
                        <View >
                            <TouchableHighlight onPress={  btnZooMais }   >
                                <Image style={style.imgMenu} source={zooMais } />
                            </TouchableHighlight>
                        </View>  

                        <View>
                            <TouchableHighlight onPress={ capitureScreen }>
                                <Image style={style.imgMenu} source={ imgScreeshot } />
                            </TouchableHighlight >
                        </View>

                        <View>
                            <TouchableHighlight onPress={ btnZooMenos } >
                                <Image style={style.imgMenu} source={ zooMenos } />
                            </TouchableHighlight>
                        </View>

                    </View>
                </View>
            </View>
      
        
        );
        
    }
}

const style = StyleSheet.create({
    viewPrincipal:{
        flex: 1    
    },
    viewImagem:{        
        flex:10,  
        justifyContent:'center',
        alignItems:'stretch'        
    },
    viewRodape:{   
    flex:1.3   
    },
    viewMenu:{
        flexDirection:'row',
        justifyContent: 'space-between'
    },  
    imgMenu:{
        margin: 0,
        marginBottom:0     
      },   
    video:{
        flex:1
        }
});
```

Comment: What do you mean exactly with "saving to device" then? You'll have to expand on your precise use-case. Furthermore, here's what react-native-view-shot has documented on saving to a file: https://github.com/gre/react-native-view-shot#saving-to-a-file

Comment: I am not able to find an image in the cache have you solved this please help

Answer (score 2):

```
import React, { useRef } from "react"; // import useRef hook on top

const cardRef = useRef(); // Use this hook inside your func. component *important

// Define a function like this
const saveAsImage = async () => {
    try {
      const result = await captureRef(cardRef, {
        result: "tmpfile",
        quality: 1,
        format: "png",
      });
      MediaLibrary.saveToLibraryAsync(result);
    } catch (e) {
      console.log(e);
    }
  };
```

Apply a prop eg. `parentRef={cardRef}` to your component, make sure the ref name matches which in this case is "cardRef".

Give any Button/TouchableOpacity

```
onPress={() => {saveAsImage();}}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure react-native-view-shot is correctly linked in XCode (might require a manual installation, 
[refer to React Native doc](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/linking-libraries-ios.html)).

Answer (score 0):

To solve this problem you have to go on your App permission on your real mobile and allow for camera storage then you can easily save your ViewShot on Your Mobile.

- go to App Permisssion in your App.info
- allow Camera accesss storage

Answer (score -1):

To save the screenshot to the camera roll, use this one: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/cameraroll.html#savetocameraroll

More info: https://github.com/gre/react-native-view-shot Check the FAQ section

Comment: can you please check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58802180/not-able-to-find-image-in-cache-using-npm-react-native-view-shot