# Not able to find Image in cache using npm react-native-view-shot

Tags: react-native, screenshot, screen-capture, react-native-view-shot

I am using [npm react-native-view-shot](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-view-shot) to capture the view in the image and save locally on the device.

When I try to take `snap-shot` using the following code I get `path` but not image at the location, below is code and output

**Path:-** `file:///data/user/0/com.caryn/cache/ReactNative-snapshot-image5936120548912611616.jpg`

```
captureRef(this.ref, this.state.value)
        .then(res =>
            this.state.value.result !== "file"
                ? res
                : new Promise((success, failure) =>
                    // just a test to ensure res can be used in Image.getSize
                    Image.getSize(
                        res,
                        (width, height) => (console.log(res, width, height), success(res)),
                        failure)))
        .then(res => {
            this.setState({
                error: null,
                res,
                previewSource: {uri: res}
            })
            console.log(res)
        })
        .catch(error => (console.warn(error), this.setState({error, res: null, previewSource: null})));
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [react-native-view-shot](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-view-shot) documentation.

Import  `import {captureRef} from "react-native-view-shot";`

I have solved the following problems.

1. Saving the `snap` to locale storage and
2. The image in view was getting blur on capture snap

   [you can also refer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56220096/react-native-view-shot-capturing-blur-screenshots)

> Write state in the `constructor` as following you can add `height` & `width` to `value` in state

```
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.ref = React.createRef();
    this.state = {
        previewSource: null,
        error: null,
        res: null,
        value: {
            format: "jpg",
            quality: 0.9,
        }
    }
```

Create view ref using `collapsable={false}  ref={(ref) => this.ref = ref}`

**On button press**

```
    <Button title={'press me'} onPress={() => this.snapshot()}/>
```

**Call Following method**

```
    snapshot() {
       captureRef(this.ref, this.state.value)
        .then(res =>
            this.state.value.result !== "file"
                ? res
                : new Promise((success, failure) =>
                // just a test to ensure res can be used in Image.getSize
                Image.getSize(
                    res,
                    (width, height) => (console.log(res, width, height), success(res)),
                    failure)))
        .then(res => {
            this.setState({
                error: null,
                res,
                previewSource: {uri: res}
            })

            CameraRoll.saveToCameraRoll(res)
                .then(Alert.alert('Success', 'Photo added to camera roll!'))
                .catch(err => console.log('err:', err))
        }).catch(error => (console.warn(error), this.setState({error, res: null, previewSource: null})));
}
```

> Save Image to locale storage using the following code

- Install `npm @react-native-community/cameraroll`
- Import `import CameraRoll from "@react-native-community/cameraroll";`

  ```
  CameraRoll.saveToCameraRoll(uri)
      .then((resp) => Alert.alert(resp))
      .catch(err => console.log('err:', err))
  ```